# react-router-dom Route with url params does not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to using react router dom. I have the following routes:

```
function App() {

  return ( 
    <div>
         <Router>    
            <UserContextProvider>
            <NavBar/>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
              <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>}/>
              <Route path={'/profile/:id'} element={<Profile/>}></Route>
            </Routes> 
            </UserContextProvider>
          </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but when I try to navigate to "https://localhost:3000/profile" or "https://localhost:3000/profile/3" My Profile component does not load
and the console gives me this output:

No routes matched location "/profile"
OR
xhr.js:210 GET http://localhost:3000/profile/authors/2 404 (Not Found)

How can i fix this so that for now /profile and profile/:id where id is any character renders the Profile component?

Comment: Do you have anything like codesandbox or similar where someone can access this example to answer in a better way?

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-route-with-url-params-does-not-render-component-qd71u4) and can't reproduce any errors. The code is fine. One of the errors is saying you don't have a `"/profile"` path, but it is there. Try restarting your development server.

Answer (score -1):

Please try removing {} around path-

```
<Route path='/profile/:id' element={<Profile/>}></Route>
```

Comment: `<Route path={'/profile/:id'} element={<Profile/>}></Route>` is valid JSX.